# Can I start an executable in an approved application?

Tags: android, google-play, processbuilder

I've noticed that it is possible on `Android` to change the permissions on a file with `chmod`, which means we can easily execute anything from an application:

```
var runtime = Runtime.GetRuntime();
runtime.Exec("chmod 0755 /my/file").WaitFor();
// Then ProcessBuilder to execute it.
```

Would Google Play Store accept an application that takes advantage of this flaw? I can't find any documentation about it, but I confirm that it works.

Actually, I want to include `ffmpeg` for tasks that are too slow to be executed using `MediaCodec`.

(I've also noticed that the `Android` framework sometimes directly access to a native version of `ffmpeg`, so maybe I could access it directly from the phone?)

Comment: on which version of android you made these observations?

Comment: For the observation: On API 18. I'm not at home so can't paste it here, but If I remember correctly, I see a call to FFmpeg when using MediaCodec on my Xperia Z. And this is not some obscure verbosy logcat stuff as I see this in the Application Output window of Xamarin. I'll try to find it and paste it here.

Comment: In the G+ Android community, someone told me he did it in the past without having the app rejected. That's all the info I got so far. Being able to run any process from an app is a big security issue, so I'm surprised I can't find anything on the interwebz about these types of situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure if it is ok for Google Play.

However i don't think it is security issue. You will exec process with the autorisation of your app.
I hope the following example will help you.
You can try the following command line with your device connect.

```
adb shell
```

To have a shell on your devices
Then you can try to look what is inside the files for an app (replace com.your.package by the name of a debbugable apk)

```
ls /data/data/com.your.package
```

This command will failde because you have not the good permission.
Now run the following command.

```
run-as com.your.package
```

You will now exec your command line with the same permission as your app.
You can now retry the previous `ls` command. It will work. However it will not work for another package.

So, i think the command you will exec with your code, will be exec with the privilege of your app. So i don't think you can elevate the privilege of you app on a file with this method.

Comment: Interesting! It would be great if providing the code was mandatory as they could see this is just a clean ffmpeg executable, but if it goes through the permission process, then I agree the risk is accepted by the user and the programmer. Thanks!